# Program crashing when accessing a specific struct member

Tags: c++, struct, crash, member

No matter what I do I can seem to access x even though it is implemented nearly the same as y. Im unsure If its some kind of memory access issue. The program breaks at the first access of x with no compile errors or warnings.
Calling step in the CPU works fine if x is not there. Any help is wonderful.

ESys.h

```
#pragma once

namespace ESYS
{
    struct InterconnectI
    {
        int y;
        std::vector<uint8_t>& Ip;
        std::vector<uint8_t>& Ir;

        InterconnectI(std::vector<uint8_t>& p, std::vector<uint8_t>& r);
        ~InterconnectI(){};
        void hi(int n);

    };

    struct CPUI
    {
        int x;

        CPUI();
        ~CPUI(){};
        void step(InterconnectI* i);

    };

    struct SystemI
    {
        CPUI* CPU;
        InterconnectI* Interconnect;

        SystemI(std::vector<uint8_t>& p, std::vector<uint8_t>& r);
        void Step();
    };
}
```

ESys.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ESys.h"

namespace ESYS
{

    InterconnectI::InterconnectI(std::vector<uint8_t>& p, std::vector<uint8_t>& r) : Ip(p), Ir(r)
    {
        y = 0;
    }

    void InterconnectI::hi(int n)
    {
        std::cout << "Interconnect " << n << std::endl;
    }

    CPUI::CPUI()
    {
        x = 5;
    }

    void CPUI::step(InterconnectI* i)
    {
        std::cout << "Step CPU -> " x;  //Accessing doesn't work...
        i->hi(x);                       //Passing doesn't work...
    }

    SystemI::SystemI(std::vector<uint8_t>& p, std::vector<uint8_t>& r)
    {
        CPUI* CPU = new CPUI();
        InterconnectI* Interconnect = new InterconnectI(p, r);
    }

    void SystemI::Step()
    {
        CPU->step(Interconnect);
    }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ESys.h"

std::vector<uint8_t> pDat;
std::vector<uint8_t> rDat;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    ESYS::SystemI ESystem(pDat, rDat);
    ESystem.Interconnect->y = 11;

    for (;;)
    {
        ESystem.Step();
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
SystemI::SystemI(std::vector<uint8_t>& p, std::vector<uint8_t>& r)
{
    CPUI* CPU = new CPUI();
    InterconnectI* Interconnect = new InterconnectI(p, r);
}
```

The results of `new` are assigned to the local variables `CPU` and `Interconnect`. The data members `SystemI::CPU` and `SystemI::Interconnect` remain uninitialized.

Comment: How can i Initialize them? Ive tried everything Ive found on the subject but I must be missing something.

Comment: You can just remove the local variable definintions: `CPU = new CPUI(); Interconnect = new InterconnectI(p, r);`. Although, it is better to consider using smart pointers